# Added code-first entity doesn't lazy-load properties

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, code-first

I have a problem where a property of a newly added entity is not lazy-loaded, if required immediately after adding the entity.

For example:

I have a User entity with a virtual JobRole property:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual JobRole JobRole { get; set; }
    public int JobRoleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then add a new User:

```
public User Add(User user)
{
    var addedUser = _myContext.Users.Add(user);
    myContext.SaveChanges();
    return addedUser;
}
```

The returned reference to the new User is then passed to a Razor view, where it tries to display the JobRole (eg JobRole.Name).  At the point that the User is passed to the View, it has:

- JobRoleId set correctly to an integer value.
- JobRole = null

I would then expect JobRole to be lazy-loaded, when used by the View, but it isn't and results in a null-reference exception.

Is this expected behaviour, or is there a way to get newly added entities to lazy-load their properties?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Environment:
Using Entity Framework 4.2 code-first.
Lazy-loading enabled.

Comment: I had this problem and the answer is correct. However, my code uses database-first. So I suggest you editing the title so future search can land here more easily.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because the [DbSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method returns *the same* object that has been passed to it as argument, which in your case isn't a proxy instance hence lazy loading is not available.

You should create the `User` object that's being passed to [DbSet.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) using the [DbSet.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method, which will return *a proxy instance*, and then assign its properties before persisting it through the [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
public User Add(User user)
{
    var newUser = _myContext.Users.Create();

    // Copy the property values from 'user' to 'newUser' e.g.
    // newUser.Name = user.Name

    _myContext.Users.Add(newUser);
    myContext.SaveChanges();

    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved my problem - many thanks. To copy the user properties I just added a line before SaveChanges(): _myContext.Entry(newUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);  Seems to work fine.

Comment: @Steve That's even better. I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things, the first one is enforce the eager-loading:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

If this doesn't work, you can load the property using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382880.aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. However, turning off lazy loading doesn't make everything eager-load - you need "include" statements for that which only apply when retrieving items, not adding them.  I can load the property manually but I am really trying to understand why this doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Well, probably because you are not enforcing the loading with the include method. If your context is lazy-loaded the relationship property of the class will be loaded because is an attribute of you entity, but the property that is in fact the relationship will not.